# Why Windows 7 display an error message when I double click on file named as INIT.BCP.BAT

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have created a BAT script file named INIT.BCP.BAT on my desktop that contains (to be simple) only following lines

```
echo Hello
pause
```

When I doubleclick on it, Windows 7 displays following message.

[image]

If first point character is replaced by minus character so that filename becomes INIT-BCP.bat, the script run correctly.

If BCP is replaced by BCPX, the script run correctly.

If BCP is replaced by DOC or DOCX or DOCZONE, Windows displays previous message.

I have tested the same thing on my PC on Windows 10 and I **don't** have this problem.

If I run the same script `as Administrator`, I **don't** have this problem.

**Question:**

What is happening ? **Why `INIT-BCP.BAT` is accepted and NOT `INIT.BCP.BAT` ?**

Is this problem linked to specific Windows security policies ?

**Complementary informations:**

The antivirus software used is McAfee.

On my personal PC at home (Windows 10), I use Bitdefender.

Comment: Windows thinks the file extension is `bcp.bat` and not `.bat` ...

Comment: Ok, but why it is not the case on Windows 10 ?

Comment: No idea. I don't run Windows 10.

Comment: ok. But if you have Windows 7, can you make the test to see if you have same behavior ?

Comment: Hmm. It works for me. But I don't useBitdefender.

Comment: Ok thanks. It is good. That will say that the problem is linked to McAfee or to security policies defined in my company. I will try to make a test in deactivating McAfee. Thanks for your help.